# Maven WebApp Project in Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I followed steps mentioned in most sties for setting up webapp maven project  .The directory structure it created was as follows.

SampleWebApplication

```
|-- pom.xml
|-- src
    |-- main
    |   |-- resources
    |   |-- webapp
    |   |     |-- index.jsp
    |   |-- WEB-INF
    |   |     |-- web.xml
```

But why is java folder not created .I created a java folder  and typed java code but there was no compilation issue at all.

Please help with proper steps.

My Pom.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.tutorials</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-tutorial</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>hibernate-tutorial Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate gives you a choice of bytecode providers between cglib and javassist -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>hibernate-tutorial</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: where did you create your `java`folder?

Comment: Please include a minimal version of your pom.xml.

Comment: which archetype did you used to create your webapp project?

Comment: maven-archetype-webapp is the archetype after creating project i run external configuation eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0

Comment: If you are using eclipse kepler, then you can use "New Maven Project" and it will have everything on-its-place created.